# Antlr token definition for a string token

Tags: c#, antlr

I am having trouble with my string token definition for my Antlr grammar.

I am currently using the following:

```
String_tok : '"' ( ~["\n\r] | '\\"')* '"' ;
```

It seems to work on tokens like this:  `"This is a STRING"`

However, it does not work on this:  `"This is a \"STRING\""`

I have tried a few variations and I can get things that work on one but not the other.  I would appreciate some help figuring this out.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mephy nope, that's totally the lexer's job.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
String_tok : '"' ('\\' ["\\] | ~["\\\r\n])* '"' ;
```

Basically, the first part of the alternation lets you use `\"` and `\\` escapes, and the second part takes everything else. This means excluding the `\` character too.

In your original pattern a `\` character in the string gets consumed by the `~["\n\r]` expression and never makes it to the `'\\"'` expression.

Comment: I tried that and it broke somewhere else. I am trying to figure it out.  I am  confused by the use of the escape slashes in the rule.  How does Antlr interpret this?  You use the quotes without the escape on the edges to denote the edges of the string you wish to capture.  So Antlr recognizes the quotes as a character without having to escape them here.  Now the all quotes that are inside the string must be the escaped or that would indicate the end of the string.  But since Antlr handles unescaped quotes the escaped quote we are checking for is represented as '\"' and not '\\"'.  right?

Comment: ANTLR interprets everything in single quotes literally except for the backslash, so `'"'` means a literal quote character, and `'\\'` means a single backslash character. So I am using a pair of single quotes to escape the double quotes on the edges.

Comment: I think I have it working now.  I had to add a little to account for '\n' and '\t'.